# I can't slide the screen by touching, Python 3 tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, touch, screen, slide

I'm trying to write a new app, using Python 3.6 and tkinter gui. I added canvas, scrollbar widgets, I coded mouse wheel event and everything works fine on windows. But when I use touch screen, I face a problem. I can click buttons, select widgets and slide the screen with scrollbar by touching. But I can't slide screen down and up when I try to touch and slide any other place on the screen like I did on windows via mouse wheel event.

Thanks,
Semih.